# T-SQL: Convert varchar date column to date type

Tags: t-sql, date

I have the following column `date` in a SQL Server database.

The datatype is currently `varchar`, and the dates are stored in the following format: `2010-04-24`

I'm running the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE games ALTER COLUMN date date
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from
>   character string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There might be a few dates that don't work. Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? 2008 I presume, if you have a `DATE` datatype - right?

My suggestion would be:

1) Create a new column of type `DATE`

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Games
   ADD NewDate DATE
```

2) Run an update script on your table and see which entries might not convert into `DATE`

```
UPDATE dbo.Games
SET NewDate = CAST([date] AS DATE)
WHERE ISDATE([date]) = 1
```

The check for `ISDATE() = 1` should filter out those entries that cannot be converted to a `DATE` datatype.

Once all your entries have been successfully converted, you could always drop the old `[date]` column and rename the new column back to `[date]` - but using a reserved word like `DATE` for a column name isn't really smart - I'd try to use something more speaking, something more expressive (relating to the problem domain you're in).

Comment: Sounds good, but now I'm getting the following error when I try to run the Update line: ERROR: The executeQuery method must return a result set.

Comment: I'm running the script directly using RazorSQL.

Comment: @kylex: OK - then your tool must have a funny requirement.... this statement should work just fine in SQL Server Mgmt Studio....

Comment: NVM, the edit tool in RazorSQL was limiting my abilities. I used a different approach and it worked. Thanks!